# how set checkbox value to checked from controller in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

i got a checkbox in my view and i want to set that as checked from mvc controller.
Here is my checkbox

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="filtroReperibilita" id="filtroReperibilita" style="height:25px; width:25px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;" />
</td>
```

I have the value that i want to set to it in session.
can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1, If using ASP-Core:**

use `asp-for` Tag Helper and set property `true` in the controller.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool FiltroReperibilita { get; set; }
}

<td>
   <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="FiltroReperibilita"/> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FiltroReperibilita)
</td>
```

For more information about Tag Helpers see [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**Solution 2:**

Consider the previous model and use this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filtroReperibilita" id="filtroReperibilita" class="form-check-input" @(Model.FiltroReperibilita ? "checked" : string.Empty) />
```